# Torricelli's law modelling Sphere

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Struggling connecting Water-volume to time. Could anyone be kind and guide me in the right direction?

> A spherical tank is filled with liquid. A tap in the bottom of the
>   tank opens, and the liquid starts to drain. After one hour is The tank
>   emptied halfway. How long does it take before it is completely empty?
>   (The flow is assumed to follow Torricelli's law: its is proportional
>   to the square root of the surface

So far I'm mostly grasping at straws.

I've come up with 
$V'(x) = -k\sqrt{h}$

Assuming r=1 =>

$V(h) = \int_0^h\pi(1-y^2)dy $

$V(h)$ is a primitive to  $V'(h) = \pi (1-h^2)$

$V(h=1)= \frac{2\pi}{3}$
$V(h=\frac{1}{2})= \frac{2\pi}{6}$

$ t = 0 \iff h = 1$,
$ t = 1 \iff h = \frac{1}{2}$

Not sure how to connect this to time further to figure out when 
$\int_0^tV'(t)dt$ = 0

Comment: Thanks! Hope this is more in accordance!

Comment: Yes, it is. Note that you can obtain the $\iff$ sign by typing `\iff`.

Comment: Ah, great was looking for that one!

Comment: Caution: "proportional to the square root of the surface" is not $k\sqrt h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For a sphere of radius $1$,

$$V(h)=\pi\int_{-1}^h(1-h^2)\,dh$$ so that

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}=\pi(1-h^2)\frac{dh}{dt}=-k\sqrt h.$$

Then

$$(h^{-1/2}-h^{3/2})\,dh=-k\,dt$$ and by integration

$$-2h-\frac25h^{5/2}=C-kt.$$

From the given conditions, you can draw $k$ and $C$.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Toricelli's law states that $$\frac{dV}{dt}(t) = -k\sqrt{h(t)}$$

To find the dependence $V(h)$, recall the formula for the volume of a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) of height $h$:
$$V(h) =\pi\left(h^2-\frac{h^3}3\right)$$

To connect the two, use the chain rule:

$$-k\sqrt{h} = \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt} = \pi(2h-h^2)\dot{h}$$

Hence $$T = \int_0^T dt = \int_2^{H} \frac{\pi(2h-h^2)\,dh}{-k\sqrt{h}} = \frac{\pi}{15k}\left(3H^{5/2}-10H^{3/2} + 16\sqrt2\right)$$
because at the beginning $H = 2$.

If $T = 1$ then half the volume has flown out, i.e. $H = 1$ so $$1 = \frac{\pi}{15k}\left(3-10+16\sqrt2\right) = \frac{\pi}{15k}(-7+16\sqrt2)$$
which gives you $k$.

The entire water has flown out when $H = 0$ so
$$T = \frac{\pi}{15k} 16\sqrt{2} = \frac{16\sqrt2}{-7+16\sqrt2}$$